# Ubuntu 16.04.6 freezes during shutdown and restart

Tags: boot, 16.04, dual-boot, shutdown, restart

Hi I'm having some issue regarding Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm unable to fix it after lot of trials.
I am having dual boot of Ubuntu 16.04.6 with Windows 7.

Whenever I try to Restart the Ubuntu it gives a complete **"Black Screen".**

Whenever I try to shutdown it freezes after "Reached Target Shutdown"
and forcefully both the times I had to hard restart it by pressing power button.

Solutions tried up till now:

- boot repair
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`
- `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"`
- In recovery mode trying for broken packages but its getting aborted

None of the solutions worked. Earlier I was having issue in booting up too, but somehow it seems that it has recovered from it.

But restart and shutdown are NO solution.

System config:

- Dual boot Windows and Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS with 8GB RAM
- kernel version 4.4.0-154 and kernel version 4.4.0-157
- Intel Bay Trail processor
- Inbuilt Intel Graphics (no NVIDIA)

**EDIT:** sometimes I can boot perfectly while using the system also there is no freeze but every-time when I do restart or shutdown it freezes completely.

I did boot repair from system itself not from live CD and here are the results in [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vtKSKzn3F3/)

For the command `sudo fsck -f /` in recovery mode the results are:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13
/dev/sda5 is mounted.
e2fsck: cannot continue, aborting.
```

When I ran recovery mode for old kernel 4.4.0-154 there was one failure:

```
Failed to start Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime
```

Comment: earlier both the OS failed to boot it was having Black Screen of Death. after I gave it for repair he replaced some rusted IC and cleaned the motherboard. when I got back the laptop from repair shop Windows started working perfectly fine not even single glitch but ubuntu is freezing. In hope to solve this I did sudo apt-get update but not getting any solution. Did above mentioned workaround but still No success.

Comment: @Nmath I have edited the post as per your guidelines. I have mentioned the boot repair link in post still I'll mention it here  http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vtKSKzn3F3/

Comment: @Nmath here are the boot repair results done from live USB http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MvBcHPW3Fd/ and yes sometimes booting also not hassle-free.

Comment: yes I am thinking the same now since there is no trace of solution seen. what would you advice re-installing 16.04 again or new version 18.04. I am having Intel Bay Trail processor with 8GB Ram and Intel HD graphics. will this suite 18.04 ?

Comment: @Nmath I get this error msg whenever I do boot repair "The boot files of OS are far from the start of the disk". I have read that this has to do with /boot partition at start of the disk but my partition system is like https://imgur.com/RAQR6Mp. If during re-install I will make four primary partition ext4, Swap, and 2 Ntfs then there is no place for 5th partition I can make for /boot. How can this be solved since I have read that keeping extended partition will cause booting problem.

Comment: @Nmath when Installing Ubuntu this error message are displayed on screen  1) "ACPI Error: [\_PR_.CPU0._PPC] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psargs-364)"     2) "ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0.IPCL, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/psparse-550)"    https://imgur.com/a/fPJ87Wt what are these errors

Comment: @Nmath Thank you for guiding me as your guidance helped me to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question. After trying all the solutions from the internet which are mentioned in the question itself and even after trying different OS(Ubuntu 18.04, Linux Mint) finally I figured it out what was causing the issue. There is one entry in BIOS known as **"USB 3.0 Configuration in Pre-OS"** which was **Enabled** by default. Once the entry was Disabled shutdown, restart everything started working fine. Also to mention now I have completely moved on from windows and now running only linux OS. For some people turning Off **"USB 3.0 legacy"** mode might also work.